# Chemfig: set points at ends of bonds

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I'm trying to represent the electrons in the bonds between atoms by drawing points at the end of each bond segment. Something like this: [image: CO2 diagram]

Is there any way I can do this? I can get something similar with `\lewis` but the dots don't quite align with the bonds:

```
\lewis{0:2:6:,O}=\lewis{0:4:,C}=\lewis{2:4:6:,O}
```

[image: CO2 diagram with dots offset]

Comment: Can you please provide a complete example showing what you have done?

Comment: Just added; thanks for pointing that out! My apologies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the distance between the dots in `\lewis` with the macro `\setlewisdist`. Note that this also affects the distance between the electrons above and below the `O`, but that is probably good in terms of consistency. A distance of `0.2em` seems to fit with the bond lines.

**Important note:** the `\lewis` macro has been deprecated in current versions of `chemfig` in favor of the new command `\charge`. Therefore this answer will not work anymore when the command is removed from the package in the future. However, since the OP already uses the command this answer is based on it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setlewisdist{0.2em}
\chemfig{\lewis{0:2:6:,O}=\lewis{0:4:,C}=\lewis{2:4:6:,O}}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Very nice and my compliments.

Comment: Now: ```\chemfig{\charge{90=\:,-90=\:,0=\:}{O}=\charge{0=\:,180=\:}{C}=\charge{90=\:,-90=\:,180=\:}{O}}```